# python selenium slow window closed detection

Tags: python, selenium

I use simple script to detect when selenium browser window is closed.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
import time
       
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://google.com")

while True:
    try:     
        driver.title
        print('ok')
    except WebDriverException:
        print('closed')          
        break
    time.sleep(1)
```

The code works as expected however on linux machine with selenium 1.25.9 and python 3.8.2 detection on closed window is immediate, while on windows 10 machine  (selenium 1.25.8, python 3.8.5)it takes 10-15s to detect that window is closed. Any idea why such a difference in speed ?

Comment: Could be, because it's the base-exception. It has to go through every exception before reaching WebDriverException. But I have not figured out yet why there's the difference. Source code doesn't give answers yet..

Comment: I dont think so. I went trough the logs and compare them. What i found out is that on Windows chromedriver is used as sort of the bridge between Chrome and selenium. The delay is caused because chromedriver detects that Crome is not reachable and waits some seconds if it appears back while on linux there is no such thing between chrome and selenium. Im not sure if this delay is because selenium dont quit properly or this is the default behavior of chromedriver. I havent find anything online of how to control or decrease that delay.

Comment: I have tried the same script on Firefox and it works as expected on both windows and linux, but i  dont want to change it since all my previous work is based on Chrome...

Comment: Okay. It’s understandable... have a nice day! You can answer your own question to close this thread

Comment: Well i know what causes the issue, but i still dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `NoSuchWindowException`?

Comment: Id did not work. I tried len(driver.window_handles) instead of driver.title and then on except did driver.quit() which did decrease the time to about 4-5s which is somewhat acceptable as oppose to 10-20s